# Manejar cambio entre Scenes. JAVAFX sin FXML

Tags: javafx

Mi clase principal tiene el campo Stage. He creado clases que extienden de algún Node (VBox, BorderPane, etc) cuyos constructores crean y establecen el contenido de ellos mismos. Un botón "Seguir" es parte de ese contenido.

Ejemplo:

```
public class ClasePrincipal extends Application {
    Stage stage;
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.show();
    }
}

public class PrimeraPantalla entends VBox {
    public PrimeraPantalla(){
        /* Contenido como cajas de texto, combobox, cualquier cosa */
        Button seguir = new Button("SEGUIR");
        this.getChildren.add(seguir);
        seguir.setOnAction(e->{ /* Codigo */});
        /* Tal vez más contenido */
    }
}

public class SegundaPantalla entends HBox{
    public SegundaPantalla(){
        /* Contenido como cajas de texto, combobox, cualquier cosa */
        Button avanzar = new Button("AVANZAR");
        this.getChildren.add(avanzar);
        avanzar.setOnAction(e->{ /* Codigo */});
        /* Tal vez más contenido */
    }
}
```

Me han funcionado cosas como crear métodos estáticos en la clase principal:

```
public static void setSegundoScene(){
    SegundaPantalla segundaPantalla = new SegundaPantalla();
    Scene scene = new Scene(segundaPantalla,500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
}
```

Los cuales son llamados desde las clases Pantalla al hacer clic en los botones Seguir/Avanzar.

Pero quisiera conocer mejores formas de hacerlo. Si eso significa cambiar mucho mi código (aunque no hay tanto código para cambiar que digamos) no importa.

He visto varios videos en los cuales los distintos Scenes están en la clase principal u otros en los que usan FXML. No es lo que busco.

Muchas gracias a todos.